# p:fileUpload multi file issue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am creating a page in XHTML to upload multiple files by using primefaces `<p:fileUpload>` component.

**The Problem is:**

If I select 20 Files. The copied files could be 12 sometimes 17 sometimes 1. I couldn't understand what kind of bug I need to fix. I pasted Java and xhtml codes below.

XHTML:

```
  <h:head>
        <title>Sample Page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:event listener="#{MessagePanel.initializePageAttributes}" type="preRenderComponent"/>
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p:panel id="multiUploadId" rendered="#{!MessagePanel.renderedPanel}">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputText value="Upload:"/>

                    <p:fileUpload value="#{MessagePanel.file}" mode="advanced" multiple="true"
                                  fileUploadListener="#{MessagePanel.fileUploadListener}" update="multiUploadId">
                    </p:fileUpload>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Java Code:

```
public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get uploaded file from the FileUploadEvent
            // Print out the information of the file
            this.file = e.getFile();
            System.out.println("Uploaded File Name Is :: " + file.getFileName() + " :: Uploaded File Size :: " + file.getSize());
            File destFile = new File("/home/nafeel/Desktop/upload/" + file.getFileName());

            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getInputstream(), destFile);
            e.getComponent().setTransient(false);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("IO exception: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the listener only called that number of times? What does the networks traffic show you? Any errors? Any version info? what if you remove the update attribute?

Comment: It just called the number of times which is equal to the number of files that are copied. Nothing error. I try by removing update. But that doesn't works.